# Give me a use case that proves that allowing generics <T extendsButNo Super> would be a fundamentally flawed design

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism, java-8

If generics are onlly relevant and typing in compile time, why is it so disregarded to allow to define a type according to a parent which does not include the parent itself (self as boundary) as a way to typing stronger?

Of course you could only call the parent methods as the concrete child is unkown.

For instance, a `myList<T extendsButNo Number>`, would not allow `new List<Number>()`, but will do `myList<Double>` or `myList<Integer>()`

That could save as from things like allowing this in generics:

```
public class TestGeneric<T extends TestGeneric.Thing> {

    public interface Thing{}
    public static class Thing1 implements Thing{}
    public static class Thing2 implements Thing{}

    public static class Output<C extends Thing>{
        final C thing;
        public Output(C thing){this.thing=thing;}
        public C getThing()   {return this.thing;}
    }

    public static class Input<C extends Thing>{
        final C thing;
        public Input(C thing){this.thing=thing;}
        public C getThing()   {return this.thing;}
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestGeneric<Thing1> test = new TestGeneric<>();
        Output<Thing1> outputThing1 = test.getOutputGenericInput(new Input<>(new Thing1()));
    }

    public Output<T> getOutputGenericInput(Input<T> input){
        return new Output<T>((T) new Thing2()); //This works only because super interface is allowed as type

    }   
}
```

Comment: No. That works only because you're using an unsafe cast, and ignoring the compiler warning.

Comment: But under the hood its casting it to Number, if T could only be ThingX, then it won't compile. I mean, `return new Output<Thing1>((T)new Thing2())` , `return new Output<Number>((T)new Thing2())` and `return new Output<Object>((T)new Thing2())`all fail. So the only way current line can work is because it is assuming we could be dealing with Number everywhere, isn't?

Comment: I think I see what you mean now. But I don't see the point in trying to make generics safer in cases where the developer ignores the generic tyes and disregards the compiler warnings. As soon as you're casting, you're basically saying the compiler "I don't care about type safety". And generics can't help you if you don't care about type safety.

Comment: I don’t see how enforcing a `T!=Thing` rule would change anything. You still could do an unchecked cast of `Thing2` to `T` as `Thing2!=Thing`. Even if that wouldn’t work, you could still do an unchecked `(Output<T>)new Output<Thing2>(new Thing2())` with the same outcome.

Comment: If so, I believe, in the worst of cases, it would fail at runtime during casting. Curently (T) is casting to Number in runtime, indeed casting is not useful at all with the generic just to warn the compiler after my testing-.

Comment: I know it's ugly, and goes against the whole purpose of generics, but having a runtime error is much better than ending up with a List>String> that contains an integer

Comment: I don't see how the cast could fail at runtime. When the compiler has a Foo<T extendsButNo Number>, it still couldn't know what the actual generic type is. All it would know is that it extends Number but is not a Number. And the only type it could use for the cast would still be Number.

Comment: @JB Nizet Because T could only be substituted by the type itself after erasing as it is not a Number. If it manages to do so, it passes, if not, you are casting one type to another which is not a super, so the cast would fail, that is how i see it at least, but I don't exactly know how would the compiler makers design it